# updating data in Firebase firestore is not working/crashing

Tags: firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, nullpointerexception, updates

> I could not be able to update the data in firestore. on clicking the
> button the data should be updated in firestore. everything is working
> fine except when I add updatng coading

my update data funcion--

private void updatedata() {

```
    phoneNo = getIntent().getStringExtra("_completephoneNo");
    String newpassword = 
     Objects.requireNonNull(confirmPassword.getEditText()).getText().toString().trim();

    final DocumentReference reference = firestore.collection("users").document(phoneNo);
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("password", newpassword);
    reference.update(map)
            .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), loginPage.class);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sucessfully updated password", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), loginPage.class);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "failed to updat password", 
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    });
}
```

logcat shows this

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.venatusgaming, PID: 20687
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7189)
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7166)
at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:819)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27688)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7592)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7189) 
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992) 
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7166) 
at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:819) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27688) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7592) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Provided document path must not be null.
at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:147)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.document(CollectionReference.java:103)
at com.example.venatusgaming.forgotPass.setnewPassword.updatedata(setnewPassword.java:108)
at com.example.venatusgaming.forgotPass.setnewPassword.setNewPasswordBtn(setnewPassword.java:94)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7189) 
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992) 
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7166) 
at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:819) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27688) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7592) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 20687 SIG: 9

Comment: The error message `Provided document path must not be null` is saying that you are passing `null` value to get document reference; in your case it is `phoneNo`.. could you validate the field by log/debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> well I found the answer and did this to solve it

map.put("password", confirmPassword.getEditText().getText().toString().trim());